# How can I maintain that only relation is persisted/merged to database in JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, jpa

Example:
I have a Person entity which has ManyToMany relation to Citizenship entity.
Person entity:

```
    // annotations
    @Entity
    public class Person {

      // ...
      @ManyToMany(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}
      )
      @JoinTable(
        name = "persons_citizenships",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "CITIZENSHIP_ID")}
      )
      private Set<Citizenship> citizenships = new HashSet<>();
      // ...
      // setters and getters
    }
```

And Citizenship entity:

```
    // annotations
    @Entity
    public class Citizenship {

      @ManyToOne
      private Country country;
    }
```

Now the problem is following: if I received object for Person update in REST service and if I get following Person object serialized from json:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "firstName": "Johnny",
  "citizenship": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "country": {
        "id": 128
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

everything goes well and person is updated. But the problem occurs if someone called my service, but not provided all the information for Citizenship object, for instance country id. In this case while JPA is merging this entity, it cascades to citizenship and sets null for the country id, and that is a big no no for me.
Example JSON for this case:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "firstName": "Johnny",
  "citizenship": [
    {
      "id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

What can I do to ensure that only *RELATIONS* are persisted/merged and not the child entities itself. I mean citizenship does not change and user of my service should not change it through Person update. Yes I know that CascadeType.MERGE does that, but if I deleted it, then even relations aren't saving. I also don't want to use CascadeType.ALL (which includes CascadeType.REMOVE in any case, for its dangerous side-effects, P.S. I've experienced that earlier) if in any solution it needed.

Please suggest something to validate this cases. This is an obvious security issue for my application and do not want to rely on intentions of the user of my service...

Comment: If understood it correctly you would just need to set the Citizenship -> Country relationship to not nullable. After that you will get an Exception for this. I would recommend you to create dedicated beans for your http endpoints and validting and mapping them to the entities in services.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. So you say that I should mark all the columns in citizenship as NotNull, and carry the whole objects around when using my service? I can do DTOs that will include only ids of citizenships but that means to validate all of them *manually* and that is the problem I am trying to solve. Such a disappointed...